# How can I right-align these items?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using React with Tailwind CSS. I would like to right-align my navigation links. Here is a pic of what I did:

[image: what I have]

Actually, I would like to have Dashboard Team Project Calendar Reports on the right.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Transition } from "@headlessui/react";

function Nav() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="bg-gray-800">
        <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                <img className="h-8 w-32" alt="Workflow" />
              </div>
              <div className="hidden md:block">
                <div className="space-x-4">
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className=" hover:bg-gray-700 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Dashboard
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Team
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Projects
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Calendar
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Reports
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
              <button
                onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
                type="button"
                className="bg-gray-900 inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white"
                aria-controls="mobile-menu"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                {!isOpen ? (
                  <svg
                    className="block h-6 w-6"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                    />
                  </svg>
                ) : (
                  <svg
                    className="block h-6 w-6"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                    />
                  </svg>
                )}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Transition
          show={isOpen}
          enter="transition ease-out duration-100 transform"
          enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
          enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leave="transition ease-in duration-75 transform"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
        >
          {(ref) => (
            <div className="md:hidden" id="mobile-menu">
              <div ref={ref} className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1 sm:px-3">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="hover:bg-gray-700 text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Dashboard
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Team
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Projects
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Calendar
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Reports
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </Transition>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

I tried to do that `items-end` but without any effects…

You can see my project there:

[My project](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-55lng)

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could put a `flex-grow: 1` on the 'Workflow' element to push the nav to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your nav component as below, hope this can help you:

```
function Nav() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="bg-gray-800">
        <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
            <div className="flex items-center w-full"> //added w-full
              <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                <img className="h-8 w-32" alt="Workflow" />
              </div>
              <div className="hidden md:block m-auto"> //added m-auto
                <div className="items-end space-x-4">
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className=" hover:bg-gray-700 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Dashboard
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Team
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Projects
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Calendar
                  </a>

                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Reports
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
              <button
                onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
                type="button"
                className="bg-gray-900 inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white"
                aria-controls="mobile-menu"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                {!isOpen ? (
                  <svg
                    className="block h-6 w-6"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                    />
                  </svg>
                ) : (
                  <svg
                    className="block h-6 w-6"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                    />
                  </svg>
                )}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Transition
          show={isOpen}
          enter="transition ease-out duration-100 transform"
          enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
          enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leave="transition ease-in duration-75 transform"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
        >
          {(ref) => (
            <div className="md:hidden" id="mobile-menu">
              <div ref={ref} className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1 sm:px-3">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="hover:bg-gray-700 text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Dashboard
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Team
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Projects
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Calendar
                </a>

                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Reports
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </Transition>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
...
<div className="flex justify-between h-16"> <------ "just give justify-between"
  <div className="flex items-center">  <----- "delete this div and </div> also"
    <div className="flex-shrink-0">
...
```

Happy coding :)